# How to "unescape" the output of bash's `printf "%q"`

Tags: bash, escaping, printf

In bash, you can use `printf "%q"` to escape the special characters in a string. I've added a line break in the following examples for clarity's sake:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "foo"
foo
$ printf "%q\n" 'foo$bar'
foo\$bar
$ printf "%q\n" "foo    bar"  # Tab entered with Ctrl+V Tab
$'foo\tbar'
```

You can supply the `-v` option to `printf` to stick the output into a variable, rather than echoing to stdout.

Now what if I want to echo the original, unescaped string back to stdout? If I just do a simple `echo`, it includes all the meta/control characters; `echo -e` gets me slightly further, but not to a fully unescaped state.

Comment: `bash` can unescape it: `bash -c "echo ${var}"`

Comment: Neat: Thanks @hek2mgl. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept :)

Comment: Hmmm. It was just an idea. I'm not really happy with this. It re-introduces those risks which have been avoided when using `printf $q`

Comment: Right, it's vulnerable to code injection... Shame :P

Comment: ...maybe not: `printf -v X "%q" '$(touch foo)'; Y="$(bash -c "echo $X")"; echo "$Y"` sets `$Y` to and echoes `$(touch foo)`, but `touch foo` is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` and `eval` to "unescape" the string (it is perfectly safe, since it is quoted by bash already). `echo` is, in general, dangerous with arbitrary user input.

```
eval printf '%s\\n' "$var"
```

The argument to printf is `%s\\n` with double backslashes even within the single quotes, since eval will take it as one argument and then strip it (evaluate it) as is, so it effectively becomes something like: `printf %s\\n $'12\n34 56'` which is a perfectly safe and valid command (the variable even includes a newline and space, as you can see).

**NOTE**: This assumes the input is escaped from printf '%q' or similar, otherwise it is **not safe**.

Comment: This solution seems to be unsafe. `var='a b; ls'; eval printf '%s\\n' "$var"` revealed the contents of my working directory.

Comment: Well it obviously assumes the input is escaped from printf '%q', in that case it's not unsafe because ; cannot appear in the input, only \;  (its escaped form). I edited to add this information.